# not able to specify type for fields in elastic search index

Tags: indexing

I am using logstash, elastic search and Kibana.
input file is in .csv format

I first created the following mapping through the Dev Tools > console in Kibana:

```
PUT /defects
{
   "mappings": {
      "type_name":{ 
        "properties" : {
            "Detected on Date" :{
                "type": "date"
            },
           "DEFECTID": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
      }
    } 
  }
 }
```

It was successful. Then created a logstash conf file and ran it.

Here is my logstash.conf file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["E:/d drive/ELK/data/sample.csv"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/nul"
    }
} 
filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["DEFECTID","Detected on Date","SEVERITY","STATUS"]
separator => ","
}
} 
output {
    elasticsearch {
     action => "index"
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => false
    template_overwrite => true
    index => "defects"
   }
 }
```

I created index pattern defects* in Kibana. when i look at the type of the fields, all are shown as string. Pls Let me know where i am missing

Comment: Maybe is problematic to define Detected on Date because this field is with space (even the mapping was successful). Try delete the index and mapping it again without space's